# How can i add to value not set value

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can add an value of 50 not set the left attribute left to 50?

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.left = "50px";
```

I am trying to get a smooth animation effect for my picture slider.

Comment: Why not use CSS animations or (if your compatibility needs are so great) use some existing JS animation library?

Comment: Well i am pretty new to js and i want to try it out but yea it will do i guess. Only thing that i need is to add a value to an attribute of html by clicking on a button tag. SO if i click it it will ad a to "left" attribute 50px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse the value and add some value to it.

```js
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.left = 
    (parseInt(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.left, 10) + 50) + 'px';
```

Comment: I think i have to get more friends here :) your answer is right but lacks the "smooth animation" part.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question correctly, then this is a pure CSS solution.

```css
.slide {
 animation-name: slide;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-duration: 5s; /* or: Xms */
 animation-timing-function: ease-out; /* or: ease, ease-in, ease-in-out, linear, cubic-bezier(x1, y1, x2, y2) */ 
margin-left:50px;  
}
@keyframes slide {
  0%   { opacity: 0;position:relative;margin-left:-100% }
  5%   { opacity: 0;position:relative;margin-left:0 }
  100% { opacity: 1;position:relative;margin-left:50px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">this is a slowly sliding div</div>
```

You could add a class that has the animation effect you want using javascript on a button click action for example:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener( 'click' ,   function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.add("slide");
});
```

Like in the snippet below

```js
document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.add("slide");
```

```css
.slide {
 animation-name: slide;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-duration: 5s; /* or: Xms */
 animation-timing-function: ease-out; /* or: ease, ease-in, ease-in-out, linear, cubic-bezier(x1, y1, x2, y2) */ 
margin-left:50px;  
}
@keyframes slide {
  0%   { opacity: 0;position:relative;margin-left:-100% }
  5%   { opacity: 0;position:relative;margin-left:0 }
  100% { opacity: 1;position:relative;margin-left:50px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">this is a slowly sliding div</div>
```